# Issues with delimiter ("\t | \n") Java

Tags: java

I am having issues using my delimiter in my scanner.  I am currently using a scanner to read a text file and put tokens into a string.  My tutor told me to use the delimiter (useDelimiter("\t|\n")).  However each token that it is grabbing is ending in /r (due to a return in the text file).  This is fine for printing purposes, however i need to get the string length.  And instead of returning the number of actual characters, it is returning the number of characters including that /r.  Is there a better delimiter I can use that will accomplish the same thing (without grabbing the /r)?  code is as follows:

```
 studentData.useDelimiter("\t|\n");
   while (studentData.hasNext())
   {
       token = studentData.next();
       int tokenLength = token.length();
       statCalc(tokenLength);
   }
```

I am well aware that I could simply remove the last character of the string token.  However, for many reasons, I just want it to grab the token without the /r.  Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "it is including the number of characters including that /r"... So if the last character is "/r" just subtract one from the length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```java
studentData.useDelimiter("\\t|\\R");
```

The `\R` pattern matches any linebreak, see [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

I guess the remaining `\r` char is a partially consumed linebreak in Windows environment. With the aforementioned delimiter, the scanner will properly consume the line.

Answer (score 0):

Replace all Carriage and form return from your string.Try this

```
s = s.replaceAll("\\n", "");
s = s.replaceAll("\\r", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Windows-style line ending is usually: \r\n but you are ignoring \r as delimiter. Your regex pattern (\t|\n) can be improved by using:

`(\t|\r\n|\r|\n)`

However, it looks to me like what you're trying to accomplish is to create a "tokenizer" which breaks a text file into words (since you're also looking for \t) so my guess is that you're better of with:

```
studentData.useDelimiter("\\s*");
```

which will take in consideration any white-space.

You can learn more about [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).